# fprintf does not write the whole process

Tags: c, printf

I'm writing a code which takes 1024 packets from another program, prints them to the console and writes them into a txt file. Now the packets are transmitted just fine and the receiver prints them to the console successfully, all 1024 packets. However when I open the txt file, I see that it stopped writing in the middle of 972th packet. My output on the txt is like this:

```
Binary Buffer1: 01111000110 :966

Binary Buffer2: 01111000111 :967

XOR:            00000000001


Binary Buffer1: 01111001000 :968

Binary Buffer2: 01111001001 :969

XOR:            00000000001


Binary Buffer1: 01111001010 :970

Binary Buffer2: 01111001011 :971

XOR:            00000000001


Binary Buffer1: 01111001100 :972

Bin
```

It just stops after that Bin. My code part for fprintf is like this:

```
if(message_to_send[0]=='\0'&&message_to_send2[0]=='\0')

    {

        n = recvfrom(sockfd,message_to_send,5,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len);

    sayi1=atoi(message_to_send);

    printf("Binary Buffer1: %s :%d\n",byte_to_binary(sayi1),sayi1);

    fprintf(f, "Binary Buffer1: %s :%d\n", byte_to_binary(sayi1),sayi1);

    sendto(sockfd,message_to_send,n,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));

    }


else if (message_to_send[0]!='\0'&&message_to_send2[0]=='\0')

    {

    n2 = recvfrom(sockfd,message_to_send2,5,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len);

    sayi2=atoi(message_to_send2);

    printf("Binary Buffer2: %s :%d\n",byte_to_binary(sayi2),sayi2);

    fprintf(f, "Binary Buffer2: %s :%d\n", byte_to_binary(sayi2),sayi2);



    sendto(sockfd,message_to_send2,n2,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));

    }
```

This code block is in a loop so it prints all 1024 packets. I have no idea what might be the cause. There is no limit while writing into a text file right?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is it consistently occuring every time you run your code ?? Or it stops anywhere randomly.

Comment: Are you checking the file while your program is still running? Remember that output with `fprintf` is *buffered*, if the buffer isn't full when you end the loop then the remaining text in the buffer will not be flushed to disk until the file is closed or you explicitly flush the buffer with [`fflush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush).

Comment: I always close the file and open it again after both codes come to full stop.

Comment: Do you fclose the file at the end of the program and is this fclose really reached? Otherwise buffered file IO might not be written to the file.

Comment: Yes that was it! Thank you very much Werner. It was always listening to the incoming packets so never reaching the fclose. Now it is reached and the txt is complete.

Comment: Show the code for `byte_to_binary` . Also your output has "XOR" in it but your code does not produce "XOR" so there is relevant code that you have not included.

Comment: also, what is the exact size (in bytes) of the text file?

Answer (score -1):

Do you fclose the file at the end of the program and is this fclose really reached? Otherwise buffered file IO might not be written to the file.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice the comment indeed, and this answer looked more like a comment to me. It wasn't me who downvoted anyway.